# AWS Cognito: token does not have a valid audience

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I've been able to get an acces_token, refresh_token and id_token from my cognito oauth2 server.

When I'm using it, I'm getting this message:

Response header:

```
www-authenticate: Bearer scope="" error="invalid_token" error_description="the token does not have a valid audience"
```

I don't quite figure out what's that and why cognito is checking this "claim".

Here you have all oauth authorization_code flow requests:

```
GET https://rmo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=2msg79go82liljhj9ourtkevv1&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&resource=https%3A%2F%2Ft4xuv5qr51.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com: {
  "Request Headers": {
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Postman/9.27.0 Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Electron/15.5.7 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "sec-fetch-site": "none",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "es"
  },
  "Response Headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
    "content-length": "0",
    "date": "Tue, 16 Aug 2022 12:48:58 GMT",
    "location": "https://rmo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=2msg79go82liljhj9ourtkevv1&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&resource=https%3A%2F%2Ft4xuv5qr51.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "server": "Server",
    "set-cookie": [
      "XSRF-TOKEN=d3f7d609-4f24-4787-8502-d961e2ab2b8f; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax",
      "csrf-state=\"\"; Expires=Tue, 16-Aug-2022 12:53:58 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None",
      "csrf-state-legacy=\"\"; Expires=Tue, 16-Aug-2022 12:53:58 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly"
    ],
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains",
    "x-amz-cognito-request-id": "8696a5a5-c80b-440d-bf7e-9f13e535e20b",
    "x-application-context": "application:prod:8443",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-frame-options": "DENY",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
  }
}
--------
GET https://rmo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=2msg79go82liljhj9ourtkevv1&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&resource=https%3A%2F%2Ft4xuv5qr51.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com: {
  "Request Headers": {
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Postman/9.27.0 Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Electron/15.5.7 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "sec-fetch-site": "none",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "es",
    "cookie": "XSRF-TOKEN=d3f7d609-4f24-4787-8502-d961e2ab2b8f; csrf-state=\"\"; csrf-state-legacy=\"\""
  },
  "Response Headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
    "content-language": "en-US",
    "content-type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8",
    "date": "Tue, 16 Aug 2022 12:48:58 GMT",
    "expires": "0",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "server": "Server",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains",
    "x-amz-cognito-request-id": "14c86dee-3885-47b6-b630-cfb312add88a",
    "x-application-context": "application:prod:8443",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-frame-options": "DENY",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
  }
}
--------
POST https://rmo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=2msg79go82liljhj9ourtkevv1&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback: {
  "Request Headers": {
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "origin": "https://rmo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Postman/9.27.0 Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Electron/15.5.7 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "referer": "https://rmo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=2msg79go82liljhj9ourtkevv1&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&resource=https%3A%2F%2Ft4xuv5qr51.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "es",
    "cookie": "XSRF-TOKEN=d3f7d609-4f24-4787-8502-d961e2ab2b8f; csrf-state=\"\"; csrf-state-legacy=\"\""
  },
  "Response Headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
    "content-length": "0",
    "date": "Tue, 16 Aug 2022 12:49:10 GMT",
    "location": "https://example.com/callback?code=497b04c2-d202-4da5-9376-99cfba57645b",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "server": "Server",
    "set-cookie": [
      "XSRF-TOKEN=\"\"; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax",
      "XSRF-TOKEN=91f8528c-3850-4ab4-adf5-3cac6aeb6e58; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax",
      "cognito=\"H4sIAAAAAAAAAAHXACj/W3jbI+GQMX5SoZmuwzKHtgUzydRQ9ZMhd+YYKTvtGPDWBb8W7pa99bvtBPsDCSP1L2+iRSpvxtTioelZv2BjsYOmjeACYdtcaS71z5cZSieUB5GZ2deD9CRyQhWin1FCIVPQFSBhs18KmicW2hPGTznwCGCNFcQbCauqyUESm/x83IXli1QpEsokdP+qXoelKSxmDpeuABudPhRU5OO9uHwkUpbQ3XVMSMQU90Bt8hYwNNQerNxMiXbLY3WCvlMTwMcqxF5CLEyYGv67uJ0wYKBi7bbQtAh1yAla1wAAAA==.H4sIAAAAAAAAAAEgAN//gHky0/ngyq/7p9G4S1ZIpOR5iVY5sAtWAQv3rIIts/L/D/2RIAAAAA==.3\"; Version=1; Domain=rmo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com; Max-Age=3600; Expires=Tue, 16-Aug-2022 13:49:10 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax"
    ],
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains",
    "x-amz-cognito-request-id": "d36ecdbd-6311-4dd9-a65f-07080c9e5d49",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-frame-options": "DENY",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
  }
}
--------
POST https://rmo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token: {
  "Request Headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "authorization": "Basic Mm1zZzc5Z284MmxpbGpoajlvdXJ0a2V2djE6Mml0azVpNjdoamFqYnVhY2dycWJhaDBoODN0MzB0NXZobDFuZ2I4cWE3aDdwc2g3cm1t",
    "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.29.2",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "13ac0a92-0848-47d3-b229-a1e97c4360d4",
    "host": "rmo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-length": "264",
    "cookie": "XSRF-TOKEN=5f4fb98c-1951-4cd2-8fb8-bf77de1a3d6b"
  },
  "Request Body": {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": "497b04c2-d202-4da5-9376-99cfba57645b",
    "redirect_uri": "https://example.com/callback",
    "resource": "https://t4xuv5qr51.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "audience": "2msg79go82liljhj9ourtkevv1",
    "client_id": "2msg79go82liljhj9ourtkevv1"
  },
  "Response Headers": {
    "date": "Tue, 16 Aug 2022 12:49:12 GMT",
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "x-amz-cognito-request-id": "6072c625-ca5e-4680-ac60-e489e12db146",
    "x-application-context": "application:prod:8443",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
    "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "expires": "0",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains",
    "x-frame-options": "DENY",
    "server": "Server"
  },
  "Response Body": "{\"id_token\":\"eyJraWQiOiJhMFFqOUZ2UTgzZ0R5VGxEa1U4NXp4ZlJ5UGFIcFNFSEp4OXBKaVNSUlU4PSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.sO2RHOY8p84UyHJkvPhDvEX4S5DKI45CoFQ7NWGZAoFn6veF2yJCfcDiV6OIgD132hxpDEcCJOZYvPjFjTh0P5pGed2XS-b4ER5HTUbglnTHLesv8DbOmyeahJrok79Ffi642CB6G4gR2RxBZw6N4ZrvxSIi06ZOhJMtWfDWMvySbLxivwEEChJ57ZcP_Hs0kEME0j4f964mJlln8hMa3Y3NJTVRr-bhxhNYkthU4yj3nFJu8QtGQKkN4hrK0dSE065Bo7YET-JD73BAPrVE8NOC9x99I4lRPVAH1-qLMSxxHIxLyeywz4g4jOosCZzme1aiPefA-ln0Ch-1nTlCCg\",\"access_token\":\"eyJraWQiOiJyNzVpbHNlS0NUNHVpQnFzbWsrMW1ob0YrWnB4c0czVTJYc1JmcjRZSGtzPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.wp4XHv_UCi_U2EuOCkpodKmT1ubxjWS2_G4DyYxXKDeSTx45fhdgKYNbiTN-mF8Gaaf59KC6byAN0C5h7_E-5vl5h7Xc2kKs8Fx2vAMuVbFJYu92D43-4tqVc-_u-w7dLueW5wzAd9wwvExyjZUFVJ_pUR9THB31Lk1rTdnFerts1IAv88tCbvv2MSMYEyn7rHmQqALGeEkopHDpVY3Sor3du6akBZmDQ-dUkw3oyv4Dwkl5Irc2as7ufZ5kwStApuU7K_9g_hnnEaCaI9A1q6nkYKQfrIBe_4ROVLjsmdnem6JDzsRhGsZiOqGk1K4fs2-Q6ivVbjkx37F_BdmMbg\",\"refresh_token\":\"eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.ZX-0zlrhgaKU7JHd2kGZc_IWXns-nZs_nM4hMbu-6B4zgtghAX2cfKN1oVoI0xD37fLBW2ZwAa7A23B7ykfomBkDsqIHtbXhWm4BEezByfMy2KsSSZYLOIRQwNh_5xxTBDhv1OLfoR9kSLi8a9ztMKPAWl1bjJJRj3zBhQf3RDUF4kWOBATOAJ82va1jv_PgKOLpsqxUPMSbi6tOD5hJEArIWoZ7UxYYkd3QYhPmHdVx3RhEupOYY8BjgrE2DPp9XPcE-bBNDMYuxf1-onxBzopPymcLtshOWmLiec3ful2mE1QZ8ojxiDd_3jl9qLexrIwiKeiX4POns0go2DudBw.bP2WGBjedSnpkUOz.oo6QkW147mY1Km-I-_u4XMj1pwt1NCxjYeQAZr3UMEhcDhY7iy_ajWWwzxBOBF-hwAInK-yg9h49i0zRnJAi_302hawZIy7pbIPAysEepwaJ26d5chm8a_saJ7wkDG12oZUivYTcr3bOm1mEFfyCxuTI5KP7N3OGxK_WREWGUqhE-XBKwOLyLYAc6N23Iy7pRc425ul_Nd5lBHaESs2pbNaWJOzAkXRoEw5y42PH3Wvs-ShtEO62LnoY0j00Dc0GXSL_926yX5hp-cbw46D8d_nXYg5liNSPcHbqDXgCIGy-hGlCP8X82INm3gctj5YIgatz1VO_zmLVY6FU56RFLpePEiHu8KVUZ2XXa-6ubdEEJGU1lO9rHVr72BFu3mX1e300Pl7tVJqSriTz-k7SremYNMqIfnmRq_f3i2tFjLueuYrgE9XqWJob3m6OMMiu1y4Cuenzle6eW3bIa3dzeuCKDtJbAmP7EggJrIWHTFcRJqVJMYBfe58yN7HvWP0dhfqEjG831dPjxY3iBzXzGqS4fs3jGR7xPQXiXOxln2v4dcfxdaATXEZwe1OBLYfJLbGulFZL8yZlOKLMX6ryrfrE8eJ-ZIs1wJFivoJvOFRO4IC0T4-5TN8BlIRMYEtcn3Fy8AmcuiPClvIV7XPUFis25xVRAaSWkahulAD7WW2Xc7NuTnDi_IEdxDXtkWHbOXt_v-T4WcpXRWg4T9gtSS3MIQ_gS4LM5HUg2haBP9tnnpGFwHHEikEpS3fddITprOnItbbOCEW4-FWY3sFLDXQr3iB4_Ly_nuD_NkfsFdq1cinCglXZ6PQV4e_3MnkX3yk55lzT8aZ1WS04A5NY9vAuhs81p7AplUSfnj_ejd8A7Zr7PXtje7-fHVkLpXaUAjiRq6xiYjk-lKoQvZHjjRlrVwogmFF1o1QQtaILsAoEVB164xXsuAzSOFF2dcH0xV7Zn4KOmv0HUR8Ylb4OUO63dVDRAH33XL_mr0aI4JnBab_0EaMXbvr7STfQDrm4_F23wRmcORT4f_tH6vBarnAR6jZGZHDTZ7bIO_vY8PSOI0HaPzPVSi2suxcriKOrASgDMKOsPc3_Qve9ZTlsp4UfOxrXMiiqbkbNExTPP2QSVi8eySCDt0ZeSKuUw2KSX1o-xQK9_r4tQ3U4zUQI8TtuUiak9CpY8iW_CYHmCfAPD39juNQWay7nymLzU_8gw_5xfOHq5Q4UZW-Djs-Bf9hkfJpX_gV1pCNP_Dk5l2cw04XBNgRpskkK3rBDK7RDtXQDIqs-rDz3vc8-SFzpyKyaqyHIDGNgSPNzXsqb.Y6U_--WSobSZxH6RCO3c0w\",\"expires_in\":3600,\"token_type\":\"Bearer\"}"
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same error when I was using a token (access or Id - same behaviour) generated by one Cognito App Client and trying to validate it (use it) with another Cognito App Client, even if the two Cognito App Clients were created in the same Cognito User Pool.

If you inspect the jwt token for the aud (audience) claim you will see the Cognito App Client Id for the App Client that was used to create the token (at least that was true in my case). I had an API Gateway Authorizer that was looking for a different App Client when validating the token.

I ran into this through a pretty specific scenario using some alpha libraries so it might not be applicable to very many folks, but in case it helps, I am using the @aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-*-alpha CDK libraries to create my infrastructure. When I create a HttpUserPoolAuthorizer I did not include my App Clients and CDK created a new App Client in addition to the one I had created and was using. When you look into the docs there is a prop where you can specify your App Clients, once I did that everything worked fine (and the automatically created App Client went away). For me, I am using libraries that are clearly marked as 'alpha' so it isn't surprising I ran into this.

Comment: Yes! It turned out I was just using the wrong value for my `Audience` field.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code flow is completing successfully and the client is getting valid tokens. The problem is happening at some later point, which you haven't included any info on.

It looks to me like you are then sending the access token to an API. whose JWT access token validation is failing. Cognito access tokens do not include an audience claim (though they should). Therefore APIs need to configure their JWT validation to avoid verifying the audience claim.

Here is some [example code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/accessTokenValidator.ts) that validates Cognito tokens. In this case I configured a blank audience to avoid validating it, though other tech stacks may provide a setting such as `validateAudience: false`.

Comment: The link returns a 404 error